# Setting minimum year in Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I want to use a calendar in android. Within the calendar, I want to set the minimum year of 1998; T the user should not able to enter a year before that. How can I solve this problem? By default it goes before 1998.

I am using following code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(WinningNumberPowerBall.this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth,cday);
mDatePickerDialog.show();
```

By using this my calendar year starts from 1900 but I want to start the year at 1998. How can I do this?

Comment: developer be more specific, In which SDK version, you want to use Calendar?

Comment: use calendar means what? do you want to display calendar view or use calendar content provider or both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
...
Calendar minCal = new GregorianCalendar(1998, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minCal.getTimeInMillis());
mDatePickerDialog.show();
```